# C++ 2D Array Alocation/Parameter Error

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic, multidimensional-array

I am attempting to create a function that takes 3 parameters (one the transmits the array between this function and main, an integer for length of first index of array, and an integer for length of 2nd index of array). Then in main, the user can set the length of an array himself.

```
void function (int** x, int length1, int length2)
{     
    int** x = new int*[length1];    //error redefinition of formal parameter x
    for (int i = 0; i < length1; ++i){
    x[i] = new int[length2];
}   
    // given loop to be used after 2d array is allocated
    for (int i =0; i <length1;i++)
       for(int j =0; j<length2; j++)
       x[length1][length2] = i*j;
}

int main()
{   
int **y, s1, s2;

cout << "Enter the rows and columns: ";
cin >> s1 >> s2;
cout << endl;

function(y, s1, s2);
for(int i =0; i<s1; i++)
    for(int j=0; j<s2;j++)
        cout<<"i = " << i << " j = " << j << "y[i][j] = " <<y[i][j] << endl;

delete []y;
}
```

I get the error about a redefinition of formal parameter x. Everything I have read seems to say that I have allocated the 2D array correctly so is it the parameters that are passed incorrectly? I have tried moving around a few things but it hasnt helped; any help or direction is appreciated. thanks

edit: If I change the parameter to (int**, int length1, int length2) it fixes the problem I described above, but now tells me y in the main function is unidentified. Do I need allocate the new array in main? I thought if I called the foo function, that would take care of it.

Comment: To get rid of the error, remove `int**`, but your function will not return the memory you allocate.

Comment: The 'formal parameter x' has the same name as the automatic variable x in void function()...  the conflict the compiler is complaining about is two variables of the same name in the same scope.

Comment: Yeah I I took the x out of the parameter  and it fixed that error but it led me to another one in main that I put into the edit

Comment: Save yourself the trouble and make a wrapper class for your 2D array that handles the allocation, re-sizing and destruction logic for you. The alternative is to manage the book-keeping on a case by case basis with a ton of duplicated code.

Comment: Having a parameter without a name (`(int **, `) is almost certainly a bad idea. You pass in array `y`, never use it in the function, and cannot expect it to be changed upon return.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. Is there any reason even with using (int ** x, int length1, int length2) the main doesnt run properly. It just crashes after inputting the the s1 and s2 so I am guessing the array y is not passed into the function correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You're not allowed to have two different variables with the same name in the same scope.  But based on your description, you should not have two different variables anyway. You want to update the parameter `x`, not make a new unrelated variable.

One way to fix this is:

```
void function (int** & x, int length1, int length2)
//                  ^^^ modify the variable in the calling function, instead of making a copy
{     
    x = new int*[length1]; 
    // rest the same
```

however this whole thing is extremely poor coding style; you should use container classes instead of a series of `new` calls.